# Error using simoid activation function in the last dense layer of a LSTN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, neural-network

Trying to use sigmoid as an activation function for the last dense layer of an LSTN, I get this error

```
ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 60, 1) vs (None,)).
```

The code is this

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_s = scaler.fit_transform(X_train) #scaled_train 
X_test_s = scaler.transform(X_test) #scaled_test     

length = 60
n_features=89

generator = TimeseriesGenerator(X_train_s, Y_train['TARGET_ENTRY_LONG'], length=length, batch_size=1)
validation_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(X_test_s, Y_test['TARGET_ENTRY_LONG'], length=length, batch_size=1)


# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(90, activation='relu', input_shape=(length, n_features), return_sequences=True, dropout = 0.3))
model.add(LSTM(30,activation='relu',return_sequences=True, dropout = 0.3))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

model.summary()

# fit model

model.fit(generator,epochs=3,
                    validation_data=validation_generator)
                   #callbacks=[early_stop])
```

If I replace the last layer declaration with the following one

```
model.add(Dense(1))
```

I get no errors, but probably also not the expected result. Any idea?

Comment: Your last LSTM should have return_sequences=False

Comment: yes right, I found it out in the meantime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause of the trouble after several attempts, as Dr. Snoopy said in a previous remark, it was in the layer before the last one: it shall have no "return_sequences=True" set, that is for all the layers before if the last one is a dense layer for binary classification using sigmoid as activation function. Therefore, this layer

```
model.add(LSTM(30,activation='relu',return_sequences=True, dropout = 0.3))
```

shall be written instead as following

```
model.add(LSTM(30,activation='relu', dropout = 0.3))
```